# Two cards are drawn at random and are thrown away from a pack of $52$ cards. Find the probability of getting an Ace from the remaining $50$ cards.

Tags: probability

After trying for hours I decided to ask. Please can anyone help me with this problem.

"Two cards are drawn at random and are thrown away from a pack of $52$ cards. Find the probability of getting an Ace from the remaining $50$ cards."

Please explain the correct method to do this.

I'm getting answer as $\left(\frac{401}{5525}\right)$ but the actual answer is $\frac{1}{13}$

THANK YOU

Comment: By symmetry, the probability that the third card drawn is an Ace is equal to the probability that the first card drawn is an Ace.

Comment: Define $X$ be a r.v that count the number of Aces in the first two cards. Define event $A$ - draw Ace in the third trial. Hence, 
$P(A) = \sum_{x=0}^{2} P(A|X=x)P(X=x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Caution: The problem says

> Find the probability of getting an Ace from the remaining 50 cards.

This is 100% since, in the worst case scenario, you threw away 2 Aces at the beginning. Then there are still two Aces in the remaining 50. Therefore, you always get an Ace.
Are you sure it didn't mean
**Find the probability that the first draw from the remaining 50 is an Ace** or something like that?
That makes more sense, especially if the answer is $\frac{1}{13}$.

Comment: Yes you thought right. It asks about the first draw from remaining 50 to be an ace. Can you please guide me where am i doing wrong. I have posted a comment on Alex's answer. That is what I am doing.

Comment: Well, I would not use calculation. I would simply make an observation about symmetry and show that it immediately follows that the answer is $1/13$. If you want to do calculations, then Alex's answer is saying that there are 3 possible cases. 1. You threw away 0 Aces. 2. You threw away 1 ace. 3. You threw away 2 Aces. You would then calculate the probability drawing an Ace given each scenario. It does not appear that your calculations show that. **Hint**: Drawing an Ace in each scenario follows a (different) hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: I got the answer. I was calculating the wrong way for P(E1) ...it will be 32/221 instead of 16/221 ..thanks for giving your valuable time.

Comment: No problem. It would benefit you to try to understand the answer using symmetry. Many questions can be solved more easily when you recognize symmetry.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it with symmetry?

Comment: I don't have any idea about symmetry..

Comment: Well, let's say you have a deck of cards with you. Lay all of the cards **face down** in a row. I ask, what is the probability of the first one being an Ace. You say $4/52 = 1/13$. Ok, but they are face down, so what about the second? $4/52$. What about the third one? It is still $4/52$ since we have no information about the first two. In other words, we can "throw them away".

Comment: Therefore, by symmetry $$P(\text{third is Ace}) = P(\text{first is Ace}) = 4/52.$$

Comment: I think i got it...thank you ^_^

Comment: No problem, a up vote or check mark would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted (^^)/....

Answer (score 1):

Basic definition - Probability is a function of 'knowledge'
so unless you know which 2 cards are thrown away at random, the probability remains the same. i.e., $\frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{13}$.
had there been any information about those two cards, which are thrown away, the answer would have been different.

Answer (score 0):

Use Law of total probability. There could have been 0,1 or 2 aces in the two discarded cards, hence you want:
$$
P(A) = P(A|E_0)P(E_0) + P(A|E_1)P(E_1) + P(A|E_2)P(E_2)
$$
can you find all these terms?

Comment: Is coming as (4/50 * 188/221) + (3/50 * 16/221) + (2/50 * 1/221) ....... Is it correct??

Comment: Thank you for giving your valuable time...i got my answer...i need to put 32/221 Instead of 16/221 in the above comment. :)

Comment: I think the term in the middle should be $\frac{64}{221}$ because you can draw Ace + other card or other card + ace